# Install pandas for python3 on Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, yum

The Fedora project lists a package called [python3-pandas](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/python3-pandas).

When I enter `sudo yum install python3-pandas` I get the message `No package python3-pandas available.`. How can I install this package? I am accessing a Fedora 20 machine via ssh.

`yum repolist`:

```
repo id                             repo name
fedora/20/x86_64                    Fedora 20 - x86_64
rpmfusion-free/20/x86_64            RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Free
rpmfusion-free-updates/20/x86_64    RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Free - Updates
rpmfusion-nonfree/20/x86_64         RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Nonfree
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/20/x86_64 RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Nonfree - Updates
updates/20/x86_64                   Fedora 20 - x86_64 - Updates
```

Comment: Check if the package is available for your system. Post the list of yum sources you are using.

Comment: I added the `yum repolist` output.

Comment: Since `python3-pandas` seems to be a subpackage of `python-pandas`, see if `sudo yum install python-pandas` makes `pandas` available for your `python3`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, `rpm -q -l python-pandas | grep python3` doesn't show anything. Only the Python 2.x version seems to be available.

Comment: `rpm -q ...` only looks for rpm packages on your local system.  What does `repoquery -i python-pandas` show?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, if the package wasn't installed at all, I would have gotten an error which wasn't the case. Anyway, I've solved the mystery in the mean time and added my answer.

Comment: `rpm -q -l whatever-package` won't return an error.  It will just report "package whatever-package is not installed".

Comment: You're right, it doesn't complain on stderr, but on stdout. Though for the record, I was sure that I had the package installed.

Answer (score 1):

As @ChristianCiupitu explained above, the package doesn't exist for Fedora 20, and

As root:

1. Run `pip --version` and ensure that it says "python 3.x" at the end and not "python 2.x". If it's not your Python 3 `pip`, find it and use it instead.
2. Run `pip install pandas`. This will install the latest version `pandas` along with any needed dependencies.

You can attempt installing the Fedora 21 package ([i686](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/updates/21/i386/p/python3-pandas-0.15.2-1.fc21.i686.html), [x86_64](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/updates/21/x86_64/p/python3-pandas-0.15.2-1.fc21.x86_64.html)) on Fedora 20, but it requires Python 3.4 and numpy >= 1.8.2-3.fc21.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Fedora 20 doesn't have the Python 3 version of this library, but Fedora 21 has it (see [RPM SPEC commit](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/python-pandas.git/commit/?h=f21&id=751e520dd7f385f5fa142d6c1f815494656c0fb5)).

As a side note, while the Fedora Packages web page for [python3-pandas](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/python3-pandas) might lead you think that it's available for Fedora 20 and 19, it's not. I've reported a [bug](https://github.com/fedora-infra/fedora-packages/issues/112) about this.

Comment: You could try contacting the package maintainer and request an update for F20.  I've done this in the past, and surprisingly it was done very quickly.  You could also take your chances with `pip` and install pandas from PyPI.